# How does service works after terminated ssh?

Tags: networking, command-line, server, ssh, vpn

I got this amazon ec2 server, running a ubuntu 14.04 amd64 server, it is supposed to be a Shadowsocks VPN server, which I deployed a Go based Shadowsocks-server on it.

Because the server is a GO based program, I have to set up those environment variables, `export GOPATH=$HOME/go  export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin`
it seems, those variables setting only last in the SSH session, once I terminate this ssh connection, and reopen a new connection, all settings are gone.

The part that confused me is, after all settings are gone, which I cannot even launch a new server without set all the GO parameter, I can still connect to the server I previously launched, it is still working. I checked process, I think it was not there.

How does this worked? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The export commands set environment variables in the currently running shell or ssh session.

If you want these settings everytime then add your commands to your bash startup file.  This is .bashrc in your home directory.

Something to be aware of is that if you ssh in and start a process it will be terminated when you logout , to keep it running you can run it via screen or nohup , this will detatch it from the the ssh session so it is not killed when the session ends. Ideally you should start this service via systemctl or init scripts then the system will ensure its running and handle the logs nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get and agree with what you said, but after terminate a ssh connect, I can still connect to the VPN server which I launched as a process during the ssh conversation. Why is that?